# re.sub convert template to function

Tags: python, regex

I'm using `re.sub` to replace ARB-style names with GLSL-style ones in a string. Now I want to additionally store all converted matches into a set of strings. Can I do this while still using the "template" syntax of `re.sub`?

Here is the code:

```
# set of replacement rules
expl_table = [
    (r'program.env\[(\d+)\]'  , r'program_env_\1'),
    (r'program.local\[(\d+)\]', r'program_local_\1'),
]
for props in expl_table:
    (re_from, re_to) = props
    # arg = re.sub(re_from, re_to, arg)       # simple and good
    def replace_func(m):
        result = ??repl_template??(m, re_to)  # where can I find it?
        declarations.append(result)           # want to save all replacements
        return result
    arg = re.sub(re_from, replace_func, arg)
```

I have found something like `_subx` in [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/re.py#L307), but it seems to be closed.
It seems that I have to implement it myself, as stupid as it sounds.

Comment: What do you mean by "template syntax" ? Which input and output strings are you expecting?

Comment: `re.sub` accepts either template string (`r'\1+\2=\3'`) or a function as second parameter. I would like to use template string, but so that my lambda is run on every replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your string while iterating over it with `re.finditer()`:

```
# set of replacement rules
expl_table = [
    (r'program.env\[(\d+)\]'  , r'program_env_dsdsds\1'),
    (r'program.local\[(\d+)\]', r'program_local_\1'),
]

declarations = []
for props in expl_table:
    (re_from, re_to) = props

    offset = 0
    for m in re.finditer(re_from, string):
        sub = m.expand(re_to)

        string = string[:m.start()+offset] + sub + string[m.end()+offset:]
        offset = max(map(len, [sub, m.group(0)])) - min(map(len, [sub, m.group(0)]))
        declarations.append(sub)

print(string)
```

Alternatively, you could "upgrade" a lambda function within the same scope. Usually, it's not allowed to use multiple statements within a lambda function but a list comprehension somewhat bypasses that constraint:

```
for props in expl_table:
    (re_from, re_to) = props
    string = re.sub(re_from,
                lambda m: [
                           (result, declarations.append(result)) 
                           for result in [m.expand(re_to)]
                          ][0][0],
                 string)

print(string)
print(declarations)
```

Comment: I have mixed feelings about your answer. On one hand, it contains perfect answer to my question, which is: "use `m.expand(re_to)` inside function". On the other hand, all the rest is so verbose and ugly, compared to what I posted in the question itself (i.e. pass template via closure).

Comment: @stgatilov: Right you are. Have added another alternative.